# filtering by field for org.apache.avro message

Tags: java, file, filter, apache-kafka, avro

The target is to consume different types messages from Kafka.
Messages are in Avro format. Every message may be presented as Java Entity.
Several types of messages have the specific field.
The output should be Avro file with filtering messages by the field.

I tried to use java reflection, but i am not sure if it the best and stable way.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Implement your custom serializers on producer side and deserializers on consumer side.

Comment: thank you, we use the copy of production, we cant do anything on producer side unfortunately